# HTML in Simple Product Name not parsing. Magento

Tags: php, html, magento

I need to have html in my simple product titles so that i can have:

```
<strong>A.</strong> Product Title Name
```

But in the front end it echoes out those html tags. Is there a way to allow all html tags to parse?

Answer (score 5):

To remedy this, follow these steps:

- Go to the admin panel.
- Under the `Catalog` menu, click `Attributes` > `Manage Attributes`.
- Locate the `Name` attribute. Open it up.
- Half way down the list of Frontend Properties, will be a drop down that says `Allow HTML Tags on Frontend`.
- Change that to `Yes` and save.
- Done :).